# Creating classes in dictionaries - values being duplicated between classes?

Tags: python, class, dictionary

So I'm trying to store some lists into a list that belongs to a "person". I tried to do this with some classes:

```
class data():
    # Contains list of x, y, z, time lists
    x = []
    y = []
    z = []
    time = []

class data_main():
    # Contains data for each Pi
    data_plot = data()
    data_overflow = data()

piList = ["Lui", "Wing"]    
rpi_data = {}

for pi in piList:
    rpi_data[pi] = data_main()


rpi_data["Lui"].data_plot.x = 10
rpi_data["Wing"].data_plot.x = 99

print(rpi_data["Lui"].data_plot.x)
print(rpi_data["Wing"].data_plot.x)
```

Problem is, I won't actually know how many people there will be. Therefore I want to create a dictionary of the class "data_main" belonging to different people.

When I try to do this, the console results are:

```
99
99
```

When I'd rather it do: 10 and 99 respectively. I'm worried that in the for loop:

```
for pi in piList:
    rpi_data[pi] = data_main()
```

I'm really just designating the same instance of data_main() to the dictionary entries, when really I'd prefer unique ones, so that they can each have their own values.

How do I achieve this?

**EDIT**: I did more digging and it turns out data_plot for both instances of data_main() is pointing to the same address. How do I avoid this (ie, every time I init a new data_main() class, that I create new data_plot() and data_overflow() classes too?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `data_plot` and `data_overflow` are class attributes not instance attributes ,so they are initialized when the class gets defined , not when the instance is created, and they get shared between all the instances of the class . You should create them as instance attributes in `__init__()` method. Example -

```
class data_main:
    def __init__(self):
        # Contains data for each Pi
        self.data_plot = data()
        self.data_overflow = data()
```

Also in your `data` class , the attributes in it are also class attributes, you should make them instance attributes as well. Example -

```
class data:
    def __init__(self):
        # Contains list of x, y, z, time lists
        self.x = []
        self.y = []
        self.z = []
        self.time = []
```

---

Finally, first in `data` class you are defining `x` as a list, and then you are changing the `x` for `rpi_data["Lui"].data_plot.x` to a number , when you do -

```
rpi_data["Lui"].data_plot.x = 10         #or the 99 one.
```

If you intended to append the number to the `x` list , you should use -

```
rpi_data["Lui"].data_plot.x.append(10)
```

Comment: yes! I'm really stupid and skimmed the documentation for classes. That'll teach me to read more carefully next time. Thank you so much!

Comment: Oh, for setting "x" to 10 (when it should be a list) that was just me testing the values out lazily. Cheers for helping